# xslt - xsl: trouble with template select statement matching with param

Tags: xslt

I'm having a problem with the following code. This code gets a value from a text box in an html page then grabs all the routes from an xml file that contain the passed in value

XML:

```
    <allstops>
      <stop number="2504" name="Main &amp; Bainard EB">
        <location>
          <latitude>42.91033567</latitude>
          <longitude>-81.29671483</longitude>
        </location>
        <routes>28</routes>
      </stop>
      <stop number="20" name="Adelaide &amp; Ada NB">
        <location>
          <latitude>42.9742886</latitude>
          <longitude>-81.2252341</longitude>
        </location>
        <routes>16</routes>
      </stop>
      <stop number="22" name="Adelaide &amp; Central Ave NB">
        <location>
          <latitude>42.9945666</latitude>
          <longitude>-81.2343441</longitude>
        </location>
        <routes>16</routes>
      </stop>
```

XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsfot-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
      >

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:param name="route" select="0"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>
      <font face="Verdana">
        LTC Stops on route <xsl:value-of select="$route"/>.
      </font>
    </h1>
    <h2>
      <font face="Verdana">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//routes[contains(text(), $route)])"/> stops found.
      </font>
    </h2>
    <table style="width:720px" border="3">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <font face="Verdana" size="4">STOP #</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="Verdana" size="4">STOP NAME</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="Verdana" size="4">LAT</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="Verdana" size="4">LONG</font>
        </th>
        <th>
          <font face="Verdana" size="4">ROUTES</font>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//routes[contains(text(), $route)]" >
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="../@number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="routes">
    <xsl:element name="tr">
      <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@number"/>
      </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
      </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:value-of select="../location/latitude"/>
      </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:value-of select="../location/longitude"/>
      </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code works but has one problem. If the users enters the route number '1' it will match with routes '10' '11' '12' and so on, so long as the route contains the number one. Also note that some routes contain multiple numbers separated by a comma like this; 01, 16, 24. In this case the user typing in '01' should still get the route with number '01, 16, 24'.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show a small sample of your XML? Thanks

Comment: Also, if the user typed in "1", would you expect it to match a route of "01" (or would the user be prevented from typing "1" in the first place?

Comment: No, '1' should match to nothing

Answer (score 0):

As you are using XSLT 1.0, one way to do it is this...

```
<xsl:variable name="paddedRoute" select="concat(',', $route, ',')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count(//routes[contains(concat(',', translate(text(), ' ', ''), ','), $paddedRoute)])"/>
```

You could remove the `translate` though, if all `routes` elements did not contain spaces

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//routes[contains(concat(',', text(), ','), $paddedRoute)])"/>
```

Note that the route should really be passed in as a string...

```
<xsl:param name="route" select="'16'"/>
```

Comment: I tested my answer here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rLW and it seems to work Ok for the input data given. Thanks!

Comment: If you are still having trouble, you could consider getting the format of the XML changed. Instead of having `<routes>16, 28</routes>`, it would be so much easier to process if it was `<routes><route>16</route><route>28</route></routes>`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `contains()`? Surely you just want an equality test? Change

```
//routes[contains(text(), $route)]
```

to

```
//routes[. = $route]
```

Comment: Problem is the user can enter route 01 and won’t see a bus stop with route 02, 01

Comment: OK, in that case in 2.0 it's `//routes[tokenize(.,',\s*')=$route]` but in 1.0 it's going to be tricky.